# Click on the first value

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have this address, "6425 Fire Creek Trl". I am automating the process. What I cannot figure out and request your kind assistance for is how to tell Selenium to click on the first search result (Permit Number B13-1351) that shows up after this address is copied in the search by. I searched the page source for it but could not find any headway.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
import os


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe")
chrome = driver.get('https://etrakit.friscotexas.gov/Search/permit.aspx')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

with open('C:/Users/.csv','r') as f:
addresses = f.readlines()

for address in addresses:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cplMain_txtSearchString').clear()       
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cplMain_txtSearchString').send_keys(address)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#cplMain_btnSearch').click()

    table = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "ctl00_cplMain_rgSearchRslts_ctl00")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate the first `tr` element under the table element's `tbody`:

```
first_row = table.find_element_by_css_selector("tbody tr.rgRow")
first_row.click()
```

(works for me)